# Which version of UUID has 0 as the first character of 3rd part?

Tags: ios, version, uuid

I have an UUID that looks like this: d30d7840-8f7f-012f-e231-1231390f85a2.

Which version/type of UUID is this? I'm looking at the version bits (first character of 3rd part), but can't determine how to identify it with a zero there.

Comment: Reopen: This is a perfectly legit question about the structure of a UUID. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UUID *variants* and *versions* are [covered here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Variants_and_versions).

*Variant* is actually the "parent" concept, and only one variant is currently specified by the UUID spec.

This UUID does not appear to use the publicly-specified *variant*, because the hex digit at the start of the fourth group is `e` (and not `8`, `9`, `a`, or `b`). What you assume is a version digit (third grouping) is not actually meaningful here, because the variant is unknown.

Based on [RFC 4122 on UUIDs](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt), your variant code is just "reserved for future definition." It's probably just a string of random digits.